# Prolog adjecent2interchange

Tags: prolog

I am trying to make a rule for an assignment but it doesnt seem to work,
the assignment is a simple tube map, and one of the tasks is to find:

stations which are adjacent to and interchange station, but are not interchange staions themselves.

I have already done the prequisite task to find how many lines run through a station:

```
station_numlines(Station,NumberOfLines) :-
    findall(M, station(Station,M), Ms),
    sort(Ms, SortedMs),
    length(SortedMs, NumberOfLines).
```

now ive got to make a rule which checks which stations are not interchange stations, in the format of :

```
adjecent2interchange(NonInterStation, InterChangeStation) :-
```

how can i use station_numlines to find all the non interchange stations?

like my guess is, run the number of lines on all of the stations from a list, then just store it and print out all of the non interchange stations.

I am just hopeless in writting this myself with near 0 experience in the very confusing language.

Stations:

```
station(al,metropolitan).
station(bs,metropolitan).
station(fr,metropolitan).
station(kx,metropolitan).
station(ls,metropolitan).

station(bg,central).
station(cl,central).
station(lg,central).
station(ls,central).
station(nh,central).
station(oc,central).
station(tc,central).

station(br,victoria).
station(fp,victoria).
station(kx,victoria).
station(oc,victoria).
station(vi,victoria).
station(ws,victoria).

station(ec,bakerloo).
station(em,bakerloo).
station(oc,bakerloo).
station(pa,bakerloo).
station(wa,bakerloo).

station(em,northern).
station(eu,northern).
station(ke,northern).
station(tc,northern).
station(ws,northern).

%adjecent stations %

% Central line

adjacent(nh,lg,central,4).
adjacent(lg,oc,central,4).
adjacent(oc,tc,central,4).
adjacent(tc,cl,central,4).
adjacent(cl,ls,central,4).
adjacent(ls,bg,central,4).

% Victoria Line
adjacent(br,vi,victoria,4).
adjacent(vi,oc,victoria,4).
adjacent(oc,ws,victoria,4).
adjacent(ws,kx,victoria,4).
adjacent(kx,fp,victoria,4).

% Northern Line
adjacent(ke,em,northern,4).
adjacent(em,tc,northern,4).
adjacent(tc,ws,northern,4).
adjacent(ws,eu,northern,4).

% Metropolitan Line
adjacent(al,ls,metropolitan,4).
adjacent(ls,kx,metropolitan,4).
adjacent(bs,fr,metropolitan,4).

% Bakerloo Line
adjacent(ec,em,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(em,oc,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(oc,pa,bakerloo,4).
adjacent(pa,wa,bakerloo,4).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this, as in all Prolog programming, is to decompose the problem into its constituent parts. Let's worry about "interchanges", "non-interchanges", and "adjacency" *separately*.

<s>Given your definition of `station_numlines/2`, you can define:</s>

**Edit:** Your definition of `station_numlines/2` is not very good because it cannot be used to enumerate *all* stations and the number of lines they are on, as in `station_numlines(Station, N)` with unbound arguments. Here is a definition that makes this possible:

```
station_numlines(Station,NumberOfLines) :-
    setof(M, M^station(Station,M), Ms),
    length(Ms, NumberOfLines).
```

Given this, you can define:

```
interchange_station(Station) :-
    station_numlines(Station, N),
    N > 1.
```

and

```
non_interchange_station(Station) :-
    station_numlines(Station, 1).
```

**Edit:** Even without the complexity of `station_numlines/2`, we can find relatively simple alternative definitions for these predicates:

```
interchange_station(Station) :-
    station(Station, Line1),
    station(Station, Line2),
    dif(Line1, Line2).   % or: Line1 \= Line2

non_interchange_station(Station) :-
    station(Station, _SomeLine),
    \+ interchange_station(Station).
```

This is arguably cleaner but, it enumerates interchange stations several times. In any case:

Then, if you also have a definition of `adjacent/2`, your predicate becomes:

```
adjacent_to_interchange(NonInterchange, Interchange) :-
    non_interchange_station(NonInterchange),
    interchange_station(Interchange),
    adjacent(NonInterchange, Interchange).
```

Comment: ok, u get it more now, however since station_numlines, is used to find how many lines run thru a station, and it needs input of a single station, how would i use it to find only the NonInterchange stations? what would the test case look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The query `non_interchange_station(Station)` should enumerate all the `Station`s that are not interchanges. I cannot test it without (some) of your `station/2` facts, though.

Comment: what i mean is that using non_interchange_station(Station), lets me test if one of the stations i enter is true, but if i wanted to test all of the stations listed at once?. so the query has to look like non_interchange_station(br) and it return true that it is a non change station. If i simply use non_interchange_station(Station) it gives me a false result. So like could it be done so i can use the predicate to display all of the stations that are not inter change?

Comment: also i get this error when wanting to query :adjacent_to_interchange(NonInterchange, Interchange) procedure `adjacent(A,B)' does not exist
Reachable from:
   adjacent_to_interchange(A,B)
   swish_trace:swish_call(adjacent_to_interchange(A,B))
   '$swish wrapper'(adjacent_to_interchange(A,B),C)

Comment: You're right that a query `non_interchange_station(Station)` did not work, this was due to your suboptimal definition of `station_numlines/2`. As for adapting a two-argument call of the `adjacent` predicate to your four-argument definition, that is left as an exercise for you.